# 14.04 Ubuntu loads an empty desktop after recent apt-get upgrade

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, upgrade, virtualbox, compiz

I run Ubunutu 14.04 on a VirtualBox (Version 4.3.20), on a Windows 8.1 host machine, with an NVIDIA GTX-660M graphics card.

I did a recent upgrade on Ubuntu and after I restarted, I could login through the login screen, and then the desktop shows up blank (no Dash, icons, etc.) and am also not able to click/right click, or open a terminal through Ctrl+Alt+T. However I'm able to open a terminal by Ctrl+Alt+F1.

I tried all solutions from several forums and all those seem to be old, and this happened after a recent upgrade (I upgrade frequently - at least every week) - hence none of the solutions worked.

Running

> unity --replace

throws up this error:

> compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded

I also tried:

1. Reinstall Nvidia drivers
2. Reinstall ubuntu-desktop
3. Ran `sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`
   and I get an `error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus wwithout X11 $Display`

Any suggestions on where else I should start, without having to loose any of my data, or reinstall Ubuntu as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but if you still have issues, and particularly if you have a line like
`(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)` in your xorg log file, consider this answer:

(Black Screen after login Ubuntu guest on OS 10.10.1)
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=65158

It boils down to ensure that no nvidia-related package is installed.
Cheers